# Trying to manipulate data, assign a list to the first item in a higher list, second item will be information about that list

Tags: python, list, nested, dictionary

Ok, I'm trying to transmit a list of values, alongside information regarding that list of values. I am trying to do that while manipulating the data. Let me show you what's going on:

```
worddictlist2 = []
for innertweet in namelist:
        worddictlist = []
        for tweet in innertweet[0]:
                worddict = {word: tweet.count(word) for word in wordlist}
                worddictlist.append(worddict)
                worddictlist2.append(worddictlist)
```

namelist is a variable with the following information:

```
[[['blah blah blah string blah blah blah blah blah blah', 'another string, blah blah blah, string string', 'string string string'], category], ['string string another string, blah', 'more words, more words, etc', 'yet again, here we go'], category2]
```

I am counting the number of times that a particular word occurs in each phrase. However I still want to keep the category assignment in some way.

I've been trying to append different lists throughout the various loops, I've tried different list comprehensions, and I'm just not seeing the result I want, which will be as follows:

```
[[{word1: 0, word2: 7, word3: 12, word4: 6}, category], {word1: 3, word2: 9, word3: 1, word4: 2}, category2]]
```

How can I get this output? Am I doing this inefficiently? The way I am torturing this data makes me feel like I am doing this process inefficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given data:

```
category = "C"
category2 = "C2"

namelist = [
  [['blah blah blah string blah blah blah blah blah blah', 'another string, blah blah blah, string string', 'string string string'],
   category
  ],
  [['string string another string, blah', 'more words, more words, etc', 'yet again, here we go'],
   category2
  ]
]

wordlist = "blah string words".split()
```

Then this should work as described:

```
from collections import defaultdict

worddictlist2 = []
for innertweet in namelist:
    worddict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    category = innertweet[1]
    for tweet in innertweet[0]:
        for word in wordlist:
            worddict[word] += tweet.count(word)

    # optional - transform defaultdict into standard dict to make it printable
    worddictClean = {}
    worddictClean.update(worddict)

    worddictlist2.append([worddictClean, category])

print worddictlist2
```

And it outputs:

```
[[{'blah': 12, 'string': 7, 'words': 0}, 'C'], [{'blah': 1, 'string': 3, 'words': 2}, 'C2']]
```

Comment: This appears to do what I want.

Comment: Can you please explain defaultdict(lambda: 0)?

Comment: `defaultdict` is a special dictionary that works much the same as the standard `{}`.  The only difference is that when you try to access a key that it does not contain, it immediately creates an entry for that key using the specified "factory function".  In this case the factory function is `lambda: 0`, so that basically means that accessing any new key will immediately create an entry for it with value `0`.  More here: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 1):

First, in the current code the `worddict` gets created anew for each tweet, which is probably not what you want.
Also, using the method `str.count()` you run the risk of counting a word that occurs in the tweet as a part of another word, e.g. `'as is the case'.count('as')` would be 2, rather than 1, since `as` appears in the word `case` as substring.
I would suggest splitting the tweet by whitespace and than iterating over the unique words in that split instead, like `words = tweet.split()` and `{word: words.count(word) for word in list(set(words))` or simply iterating over the words and incrementing the counts in the dictionary for every occurrence of a word, I'm not sure which is more efficient.

So, my suggestion would be

```
worddictlist2 = []
for innertweet in namelist:
    worddict = {}
    for tweet in innertweet[0]:
        words = tweet.split()
        for word in words:
            if not worddict.has_key(word):
                worddict[word] = 1
            else:
                worddict[word] += 1
    worddictlist2.append([worddict, innertweet[1]])
```

given the input

```
namelist = [[['blah blah blah string blah blah blah blah blah blah', 'another string, blah blah blah, string string', 'string string string'], 'category'], [['string string another string, blah', 'more words, more words, etc', 'yet again, here we go'], 'category2']]
```

this code generates

```
[[{'blah,': 1, 'blah': 11, 'string,': 1, 'string': 6, 'another': 1}, 'category'], [{'string,': 1, 'string': 2, 'again,': 1, 'etc': 1, 'we': 1, 'here': 1, 'blah': 1, 'words,': 2, 'another': 1, 'go': 1, 'yet': 1, 'more': 2}, 'category2']]
```

In order to get rid of the words with commas attached, you might want to eliminate the punctuation  before counting the words, e.g. by adding `tweet = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', tweet)` to the code above:

```
import re

worddictlist2 = []
for innertweet in namelist:
    worddict = {}
    for tweet in innertweet[0]:
        tweet = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', tweet)
        words = tweet.split()
        for word in words:
            if not worddict.has_key(word):
                worddict[word] = 1
            else:
                worddict[word] += 1
    worddictlist2.append([worddict, innertweet[1]])

print worddictlist2
```

that yields

```
[[{'blah': 12, 'string': 7, 'another': 1}, 'category'], [{'again': 1, 'we': 1, 'string': 3, 'etc': 1, 'here': 1, 'blah': 1, 'another': 1, 'words': 2, 'go': 1, 'yet': 1, 'more': 2}, 'category2']]
```

Comment: I absolutely want the worddict to be created for each tweet.

Comment: everything else seems great so far.

Comment: worddict is going to have several tweets created, and then they're all going to be assigned to a category.

Comment: No, it does not. It assigns values per word. This is not what I want. I have a word list and am assigning numbers based on the frequency in this wordlist.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
worddictlist2 = []
wdlist = {}
for innertweet,cat in namelist:
   for i in innertweet:
      for j in i.split():
         j = j.strip(',') # strip comma
         wdlist.setdefault(j,0) # if 'j' unknown key
         wdlist[j] += 1
   worddictlist2.append(wdlist, cat)
   wdlist = {}


print(worddictlist2)
```

gives:

```
[
 [{'another': 1, 'blah': 12, 'string': 7}, 'category'],
 [{'again': 1, 'another': 1, 'blah': 1, 'etc': 1, 'go': 1, 'here': 1, 'more': 2, 'string': 3, 'we': 1, 'words': 2, 'yet': 1}, 'category2']
]
```